# Как преобразовать строку вида '31 Jul 2018' в дату?

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли преобразовать строку '31 Jul 2018' в дату? Есть ли стандартная функция для этого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime('31 Jul 2018', '%d %b %Y')
print(date)
>>> 2018-07-31 00:00:00
```

Детали распознавания формата - [в справке](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) по `time.strftime(format[, t])`

Comment: Спасибо, а я блин тупил, маску не правильную писал:((( "%d/%m/%y"
А надо было такую: '%d %b %Y'